Error: "React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string or a class/function but got: object" when implementing reCAPTCHA in a React Remix app
I'm working on integrating Google reCAPTCHA into my React Remix application, but I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve. The error message I'm getting is:
import React from 'react';
import ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const handleRecaptchaChange = (value) => {
    setRecaptchaValue(value);  };

  return (
    <>
      <ReCAPTCHA 
        sitekey={process.env.REACT_APP_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY} 
        onChange={handleRecaptchaChange} 
      />
    </>
  );
}

package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "remix": "^1.0.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0"
  }
}

Using the .env variable prevents the app from loading, and I get the same error. However, when I try hardcoding the sitekey, it throws the same error but as a warning. I haven't been able to find any solution when searching online. My .env variable I also correctly labeled. Thanks in advance for any solution to thus issue.
Tried moving the recaptcha to its own component the importing. still throwing the same error. tried import { ReCAPTCHA } from 'react-google-recaptcha'; as to import ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha'; this prevented the app from loading.
